# get selected post using $_GET

Tags: posts, get-posts

im trying to get a post info when I click a button on the post and make it echo out the the same info it has in the else function, I tried adding in a query but in return it makes it echo back all the post instead of just the one im clicking on

```
        <?php $cb_bp_x_points = cp_displayPoints($bp->loggedin_user->id,1,$return,0,$format);
$cp_bp_points_for_content = 100;
if ($cb_bp_x_points >= $cp_bp_points_for_content) :
global $post; 
if(isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p']=='redeem') { ?>

<div id="redeem">
<?php
$redeem_id = $prize_id;
$the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=prizes&p='.$redeem_id.'&post_status=publish');while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
$post_redeem_id = get_post($redeem_id); 
$redeem_title = $post_redeem_id->post_title;
echo $redeem_title;

endwhile;

}else{
?>

<? $the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=prizes&showposts=16&post_status=publish');while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>

<div class="prize-1 prize">
<?php $prize_id = the_ID();?>
<div><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
<div><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'redeem_points', true); ?></div>
<span><a href="?p=redeem">Redeem</a></span>
</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php }?>

<?php else : ?>

<p>You must login</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

updated my code for better understanding...

Comment: Two things get_the_content() and get_the_title() do just that, they get the data, but do not echo it. Use the_title() and the_content() to echo the data. Just curious as to why you are using timthumb when WP 2.9+ has built in thumbnail support? See: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size

Comment: because im old school lol, on a serious note im just putting my code together and getting different things from my other codes before I complete it, but i did have the_title and the_content and the results came back blank after that so I figured I would try those 2 and its still blank, any other suggestions?

Comment: get_the_content and get_the_title are not in the loop and therefore won't work correctly because the postdata is not setup correctly.

Comment: even when in the loop it gets all the post instead of just the one i selected

Comment: `$the_query = new WP_Query('post_type=prizes&post_status=publish');` will return all posts matching the type and the status, that's why you're getting a lot of them. Try `get_post()` supplying it the ID of the post you want to get the information for instead of a query. Also don't `$_GET['post']` since `post` is a reserved variable and if it's present in the query then you're probably on a single page. On the other hand, I've not understood the question to its fullest extent, just chiming in.

Comment: I updated my code so you could maybe understand it better, what im trying to do is when i press `<span><a href="?p=redeem">Redeem</a></span>` it will refresh the page only showing the button I pressed for that results, its only get specific post info pretty much...

Comment: Where is `$prize_id` coming from? If you're feeding it into the `p` argument of the query, you can do so by `get_post( $prize_id )` no need for additional arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this worked...

```
$the_query = new WP_Query("post_type=prizes&p=".$redeem_id."&post_status=publish&p={$_GET['post_id']}");while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();

<span><a href="?p=redeem&post_id=<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">Redeem</a></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use a [reserved variable](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms) as a GET (or POST) parameter, this won’t work.